# Bound on the conditional expectation of a stochastic integral given W_T

Tags: stochastic-calculus

Suppose that $f \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ is a bounded function and let $X$ denote the stochastic integral
$$
X = \int_0^T f(W_t) \, d W_t.
$$
Is it possible in general to bound conditional expectations of the form:
$$
\mathbb E [X | W_T = x] \, ?
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define $F(t) =\int_0^tf(s)ds$ and apply the Ito's lemma to the function $F(W_t)$:
$$dF(W_t)=f(W_t)dW_t + \frac{1}{2}f'(W_t)dt$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
&F(W_T) =\int_0^Tf(W_t)dW_t + \frac{1}{2}\int_0^Tf'(W_t)dt\\
&\implies \int_0^Tf(W_t)dW_t = F(W_T)-\frac{1}{2}\int_0^Tf'(W_t)dt \\
&\implies \mathbb{E} \left(X|W_T \right) = F(W_T)-\frac{1}{2} \mathbb{E} \left(\left.\int_0^Tf'(W_t)dt  \right|W_T\right)  \tag{1}
\end{align}$$
From the [property of Brownian Bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge#General_case), we have:
$$\begin{align}
W_t|W_T &= \frac{t}{T} W_T + \underbrace{\left(W_t -\frac{t}{T} W_T  \right)}_{\text{independent to }W_T} \\
&\stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=} \mathcal{N}  \left(\frac{t}{T}W_T,\frac{t(T-t)}{T}  \right) \stackrel{\mathcal{D}}{=} \frac{t}{T}W_T + \sqrt{\frac{t(T-t)}{T}} \cdot \mathcal{N}(0,1)
\end{align}$$
then
$$\begin{align}
\mathbb{E} \left(\left.\int_0^Tf'(W_t)dt  \right|W_T\right) &=\int_0^T\mathbb{E} \left(\left.f'(W_t)  \right|W_T\right) dt\\
&=\int_0^T\mathbb{E} \left(\left.f'\left(\frac{t}{T}W_T + \sqrt{\frac{t(T-t)}{T}}  \cdot Z\right)  \right|W_T\right) dt\\
&=\int_0^T\int_{z \in \mathbb{R}} f'\left(\frac{t}{T}W_T + \sqrt{\frac{t(T-t)}{T}}  \cdot z\right)\varphi(z) dz dt\\
&=\int_{z \in \mathbb{R}}\varphi(z) \left(\int_0^Tf'\left(\underbrace{\frac{t}{T}W_T + \sqrt{\frac{t(T-t)}{T}}  \cdot z}_{=:g(t,T,W_T,z)=: g(t)} \right)  dt\right)dz\\
&=\int_{z \in \mathbb{R}}\varphi(z) \left(\frac{f(g(T))}{g'(T)} + \int_0^T\left(f(g(t))\cdot \frac{g''(t)}{(g'(t))^2}\right)  dt\right)dz
\end{align}$$
where $\varphi(x)$ is the density function of $\mathbb{N}(0,1)$ and
$$\begin{align} 
&g(t): = g(t,T,W_T,z) = \frac{t}{T}W_T + \sqrt{\frac{t(T-t)}{T}}  \cdot z \\
&g'(t) = \frac{W_T}{T} + \frac{T-2t}{2\sqrt{tT(T-t)}}\cdot z \\
&g''(t)= -\frac{1}{4}\cdot\left(\frac{T}{t(T-t)}\right)^{3/2}z  \tag{2}
\end{align}$$
Because $g'(t) \xrightarrow{t\to T} -\infty$, then $f(g(t))/g'(t) \xrightarrow{t\to T} 0$, we deduce that:
$$ \mathbb{E} \left(\left.\int_0^Tf'(W_t)dt  \right|W_T\right)= \int_{z \in \mathbb{R}}\varphi(z) \left(\int_0^T\left(f(g(t))\cdot \frac{g''(t)}{(g'(t))^2}\right)  dt\right)dz\tag{3}$$
Finally, from $(1),(3)$ we deduce that
$$\color{red}{\mathbb{E} \left(X|W_T \right) = F(W_T)  - \frac{1}{2}\int_{z \in \mathbb{R}} \left( \int_0^T \left( f(g(t))\cdot \frac{g''(t)}{(g'(t))^2}\right)  dt\right)\varphi(z)dz  }$$
where the function $g$ and its derivatives are defined by $(2)$.

Comment: Thank you very much! This indeed perfectly answers the question. In the application I am looking at, however, the function $f$ is in fact from $\mathbb R^d$ to $\mathbb R^d$, and it is not the gradient of another function $F$. Would you know whether there are standard approaches in that situation?

Comment: @RobertoRastapopoulos If I understand well, your function $f$ is in fact a multivariable vector-valued function: $f: \mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$? Then, how do you define the conditional expectation $X$? And does $f$ depend on 1 single Brownian motion $W_t$ or it depends on a multivariate Brownian motion $(W_{i, t})_{i=1,...,m}$ (where $m$ may be equal to $n$)?

Comment: Yes, that is right. I have made the set up more precise in a [new question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4842014/bound-on-the-conditional-expectation-of-a-stochastic-integral-given-w-t-multidi). Thanks again!