# Bound on the conditional expectation of a stochastic integral given W_T (multidimensional case)

Tags: stochastic-analysis

This is a follow-up of a [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4841669/bound-on-the-conditional-expectation-of-a-stochastic-integral-given-w-t) I asked.

Suppose that $f \colon \mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$ is a bounded vector field (not necessarily the gradient of another function), that $(W_t)_{0\leq t \leq T}$ is a standard Brownian motion in $\mathbb R^n$, and let $X$ denote the stochastic integral
$$
X = \int_0^T f(W_t) \cdot d W_t.
$$
Is it possible in general to bound conditional expectations of the following form in terms of $x \in \mathbb R^n$?
$$
\mathbb E [X | W_T = x]
$$
In particular, is the conditional expectation finite?

Comment: It seems that $f$ depends only on $1$ single BM and $f(W_t) = (f_1(W_t), f_2(W_t),...,f_n(W_t))' $, right? And also $X \in \mathbb{R}^n$? It suffices then to separately compute  the $n$ conditional expectation $$\mathbb{E} \left( \left.  \int_0^T f_{\color{red}i} (W_t)dW_t\right| W_T = x \right)$$ for $\color{red}{i} = 1,..,n$ with the method in the previous answer. And of course, there is no need to use gradient here.

Comment: No, there are $n$ one-dimensional Brownian motions.

Comment: The technique to solve the problem is to retrieve a scalar function $F\in \mathbb{R}$ from its gradient $\nabla F = f \in \mathbb{R}^n$. And it is possible to do that via this [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/507076/195378).

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this works only when the vector field is rotational-free (in 3d, but this generalizes), I think.

Comment: Perhaps do you have a case that the [method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/507076/195378) doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, take for example $\nabla f = y \mathbf i - x \mathbf j$.

Comment: I think there is an answer to my question in this (surprisingly little cited) paper. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022247X69901826